# Axapta 4.0 How to export a view to a different environment

Tags: axapta, x++

I am trying to export a view but the XPO exports as a Table, Is there a way to export the view or change it to a query so that it can be exported and regenerated in a different environment.

Comment: So when you export the `view` as an `XPO` and reimport it into another environment, it is created as a `table`? Or did you look at the `XPO` and see that it says `table` in the file?

Comment: The XPO says that it is a table,so it should probably create a table in the new environment, But i have not tested this yet.

Comment: AX sometimes calls views tables when reflecting on itself, but they are actually views.

Comment: Confirmed, The XPO imported fine as a view.

Comment: I added an answer so you can close the question if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AX, when you export a `view` as an `XPO`, it will say `table` in the `XPO` text file, because that's the way AX chooses to display objects when reflecting upon them for import/export and internal reference.

It will still import as a `view`.